# PHP, Codeigniter: Foreach Should Echo Multiple Rows when accessed in Controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach

Hi guys I will summarize my problem here I hope you would understand.

**Main Goal:** To have an on change event that will depend on my selected values in month that will access the controller and echo multiple rows or result.

**Already Accomplished:** I have an on change event in my multiple select that will trigger my controller and access the rows.

**The On change event:**

```
$('#month').change(function() {
  var values = $(this).val(); // returns array

    // loop over values
    values.forEach(function(val){

      if (val == 1)
      {
        $("#nomonthschoolfees").load(baseUrl+'/admin/summary/noMonthSchoolFees/'+studentId+'/'+schoolyearId);
      // This will access my controller if 1 is selected in multiple select.
      }
      else if (val == 2)
      {

      }
  });
});
```

**Main Problems:**

**Problem 1:** My 1st problem is, when it is echoing a row, the results of the datas are outside the select option box.

**Problem 2:** As I've tried my query in mysql, it should show at least 2 rows, but it is only showing/echoing 1 result of the foreach inside my controller.

**Screenshot of the forms and problem:**
[image]

**Main Code (Controller):**

```
public function noMonthSchoolFees($studentId = null, $schoolyearId = null)
{
    if ($studentId && $schoolyearId) {
        $studentfeesData = $this->model_feestudent->noMonthSchoolFees($studentId, $schoolyearId);

        if ($studentfeesData) {
            $arrayNumber = 0; 
            foreach($studentfeesData as $x => $studentfees) {
                $rows = '
                        <tr id="row'.$x.'" class="'.$arrayNumber.'">
                          <td class="form-group">
                            <select style="width: 400px; text-align-last:center;" class="form-control" name="subparticulars['.$x.']" id="subparticulars'.$x.'" readonly/>
                                <option value="'.$studentfees['feetype_id'].'"> '.$studentfees['feetype_name'].' </option>
                            </select>   
                          </td>
                          <td class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subpaymentbalance[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subpaymentbalance<?php echo $x; ?>" onclick="copyBalance('.$x.')" style="text-align:center;" value="'.$studentfees['feestudent_amount'].'" readonly />
                          </td>
                        </tr>';
                $arrayNumber++;    
            }// end of foreach

        }// end of if ($studentfeesData)
    } // end of if ($studentId && $schoolyearId)

    echo $rows; // echo the results of rows.

}// end of function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwritting `$rows` each loop.

replace

```
...
$rows = '
    <tr id="row'.$x.'" class="'.$arrayNumber.'">
...
```

with

```
public function noMonthSchoolFees($studentId = null, $schoolyearId = null)
{
    $rows = '';

    ...

    $rows .= '
        <tr id="row'.$x.'" class="'.$arrayNumber.'">
    ...
```

Also fix the closing tag (look at backslash on the end):

```
<select style="width: 400px; text-align-last:center;" class="form-control" name="subparticulars['.$x.']" id="subparticulars'.$x.'" readonly/>
```

with

```
<select style="width: 400px; text-align-last:center;" class="form-control" name="subparticulars['.$x.']" id="subparticulars'.$x.'" readonly>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it will have an error of Undefined variable: rows.

Comment: you need to set $rows='' before the loop

Comment: Initialize it first line in you method. Take a look

Comment: OK Thanks that worked, but do you know what's the solution for the 1st Problem as it results in echoing the value outside the select option box? What the problem in my syntax?

Comment: You have a backslash on your "select" tag. Take a look.

Comment: No problem. If it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted to help anyone else with the same issue.